# Facebook graph api data synchronization with local database

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am currently develop a web and android app for display facebook profile feed and page feed in my website and android app.
I done with use of facebook graph api,it work fine.but i want to store facebook data in my database and synchronize with facebok.
store data in my database and synchronize with facebook,it is right way?
I am not sure it is best way or not?

Thank you in advance.